# Experiment to measure kinetic energy stored in door

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, potential-energy

I'd like to know the kinetic energy stored in a moving door (pushed open) of unknown mass.
If the hinges were frictionless, I'd use a weight attached to a string and a pulley to determine the energy by measuring the resulting increase in potential energy of the weight (i.e. measure the height when the door is stopped).
How can I eliminate/compensate the friction of the door hinges?

Comment: Is the string attached to the door during the pushing phase?

Comment: @nasu I thought I'd give it enough slack so while pushing (accelerating) it's effectively not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using potential energy to measure kinetic energy is very sound.

> How can I eliminate/compensate the friction of the door hinges?

There's no easy way to 'eliminate/compensate' for friction. Your best hope is to *eliminate it* as much as possible. The key to that is highly efficient lubrication by means of (e.g.) $\text{WMD 40}$ oil.

---

*In answer to OP's comment.*

Assume that the door has an initial ($t=0$) kinetic energy $K$ and that we convert this to potential energy $U$ by a string, pully and mass system.

Assume also that during the conversion $K \to U$ an amount of friction work $W_f$ is irretrievably lost. The energy balance now becomes:

$$K=U+W_f$$

Suppose now that we have two different ways of determining $U$, for example using two different masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$, so that:

$$U_1=m_1gh_1$$
$$U_2=m_2gh_2$$

So that:

$$K=m_1gh_1+W_f=m_2gh_2+W_f=K$$

Clearly, $W_f$ cannot be determined from this, as it drops out of the equation.

Another problem is that the string, mass and pully system *is itself never completely free of friction*.

To complicate matters further, friction work tends not to be path-invariant.  E.g. friction coefficients tend to come down with increased velocity.

Comment: Thanks! I meant if the "experiment" could be designed in a way where the friction could "cancel out" mathematically or be determined separately. For example, if I use two different weights with the same input energy, I should get different results due to friction?